# I got java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException and a stack trace that doesn't have my code in it

Tags: java, android

I have an android application about dictionary and I got this error from Crashlytics a few times in a few months but I cannot reproduce it myself.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
   at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:66)
   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
   at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getItem(Spinner.java:841)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(AdapterView.java:795)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performClickChild(ViewRootImpl.java:880)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:122)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5122)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

No my code in it. I think it's about spinner and adapter I've created. I have 2 spinners that have 2 members (actually they're the same thing but in different page) so I don't know which one causes this error. However, I tested both of them many times and I couldn't make this error happen even for once. Each spinner work with different adapter. Here's the code to define spinner's members. They're the same and the members are fixed.

```
//////// This is in a fragment /////////////////
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spDictionary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fragment_dictionary_spinner_height"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:entries="@array/dictionary_list"/>
```

Could anyone please help me narrow the problem which area I have to check? If you need more info please let me know. Thanks.

=====================

Added relevant codes.

```
/////////////// strings.xml ///////////////
<string-array name="dictionary_list">
    <item>TWL</item>
    <item>SOWPOD</item>
</string-array>

////////////// fragment.java //////////////
//I cut only the code that relates to the spinner.

public class DictionaryFragment extends Fragment {
private Spinner spDictionary;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Utils.writeStateLog("DictionaryFragment::onCreateView");

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dictionary, container, false);
    spDictionary = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spDictionary);
    return v;
}

// Actually no adapter works with spinner directly (sorry about my first post). 
// I mean I don't pass the spinner's text value to any adapter. 
// I just get the spinner's text value as below and not use spinner anymore.

String type = spDictionary.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Or maybe it's not about spinner? But I see it in the stack trace..

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: Please post your java code

Comment: Please add spinner related code and also dictionary_list array also.

Comment: if you want to do it simple way. use`android:entries="@array/array`. you do not need to use any adapter or anything.

Comment: Just updated. Sorry for late. I'm not familiar with editing stackoverflow. And I don't use any adapter to bind directly with the spinners. Sorry for my first post. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Please Add your java code.
create array like

```
<string-array name="array_name">
    <item>Array Item One</item>
    <item>Array Item Two</item>
    <item>Array Item Three</item>
</string-array>
```

In your java code :

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
//selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Hi Piyush, thanks for your answer. I'll try to put this code to my code. However, I cannot tell you if this solve the problem or not as I never found it myself. If it doesn't occur for about 2 months I think it's ok. Thanks a lot.